# Interruption for Button and Button Press for Longer then 3 Secs

Tags: c, arduino

In my project, I have three buttons where each triggers a function.

This function have to do two things, one action when the button is pressed (actually working), but I want to add a second functionality, in which if the button is pressed for more then 3 seconds, it do something, like calling a function.

So far, i'm initializing the interruption:

```
attachInterrupt(0, footOne, Falling);
```

and the function is:

```
void footOne(){
static unsigned long last_interrupt_time = 0;
unsigned long interrupt_time = millis();
// Debounce
if (interrupt_time - last_interrupt_time > 200){
    //Do things
    if(debug==1){Serial.println("Button 1 pressed!");}
}

last_interrupt_time = interrupt_time;
}
```

Now I want to know how I can change the function to add the possibility if the button is pressed for longer then 3 seconds...

Remembering that this function is called from the interrupts.

Thank you!

Comment: You're probably going to have to change your interrupt to `attachInterrupt(0, footOne, CHANGE)` and then look whether the current value is high or low and also see when the last change was. Only interrupting on `FALLING` you'll never know how long it was on for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the way you have your program structured right now, you would need an external RTC to carry out this task.  Once you initiate an interrupt, the internal clock on the arduino is compromised and therefore cannot be used reliably until leaving the interrupt.  Is your implementation so time sensitive that an interrupt is required? Because if it isn't, polling the state of the button and then comparing the time elapsed would be a pretty easy implementation.  If you want to stick with interrupts however, I'd take a look at [volatile](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Volatile) variables as a way to talk between your main loop and your interrupt functions.

Comment: This implementation does not need to be time precise. How does polling  work? All I need is the code to respond when the button is pressed, not needing to wait for a for loop to end, for example.

Comment: What I decided to do then was a hardware debounce!